# GeckoDriver for selenium not in global path

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/USER/Documents/python/tools/swagSearcher/swagSearcher.py
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "tools/swagSearcher/swagSearcher.py", line 6, in <module>

web = webdriver.Firefox() # This is the break/error point in my code

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 135, in __init__

self.service.start()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 71, in start

os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH. 

Exception AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'process'" in <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.firefox.service.Service object at 0x7f0a7e776c90>> ignored

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'd appreciate any help with this error. - **No amount of googling got me to a solution**

And yes I tried `pip install -U selenium`

P.S. Debian based operating system

Comment: you can install geckodriver, get binary dist according to your platform, and ensure it's in the PATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So on linux; for rust applications this is the [documentation here](http://doc.crates.io/)

More documentation on gecko-driver [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver)

Instructions for a **Ubuntu** based system.

```
git clone https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver.git
cd geckodriver
chmod +x build.sh && ./build.sh
cargo build
sudo mv target/geckodriver /usr/bin
geckodriver -h
```

if compiling doesn't work for you, there's pre-compiled binaries on the github too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after updating selenium. I downgraded selenium to version 2.53.6 and with Firefox28.0 it doesn't ask for the geckodriver.