# Selenium Error loading page

Tags: python, linux, selenium, debian

After recompiling geckodriver, and moving it into my /bin directory (if you need help with that look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40195687/selenium-doesnt-connect-geckodriver-for-linux-solved/40195926#40195926))

I've ran into another problem, and I'm not quite sure how to fix it.

`/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/lyend/Documents/python/tools/swagSearcher/swagSearcher.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lyend/Documents/python/tools/swagSearcher/swagSearcher.py", line 8, in <module>
    web.get('google.com')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 248, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Error loading page`

I'm truly stuck, and it has nothing to do with my code. If you'd like to know the code, check below

```
web = webdriver.Firefox()
web.get('google.com')
```

OS: Linux Mint 17.3

Python: 2.7.6

Firefox Version: 49.0

I'd appreciate any help with this error.

Answer (score 0):

```
web.get('google.com')
```

to

```
web.get('http://www.google.com')
```

solved this issue for me on a very similar build